# The latest version of gcc to use libstdc++.so.5

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

What is the latest version of gcc that still uses libstdc++.so.5 (as opposed to libstdc++.so.6)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching all over for the answer, and failing to find it. I compiled several different versions and the last version to use libstdc++.so.5 is version 3.3 (more specifically 3.3.6). Version 3.4.X uses libstdc++.so.6.

Answer (score 7):

In the [Gnu ABI policy](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html), you can find this:

- ...
- gcc-3.3.3: libstdc++.so.5.0.5
- gcc-3.4.0: libstdc++.so.6.0.0 (Incompatible with previous)
- ...

So unless they didn't list a version, gcc-3.3.3 is the one you want.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that libstdc++.so.5 was used for all GCC versions 3.X, and libstdc++.so.6 was used for GCC 4.X. I'm not sure on this, but I do know that libstdc++2 was used up until 3.0, which used libstdc++5, and that 4.0 uses libstdc++6.